# Get all descendants LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this XML format but have removed the bulk of it as this is the only information I need to extract. The parts I extracted are named similarly, so there exist other elements named dict, key, array and string - i.e. just pulling values from the string elements isn't an option.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
                <array>
                    <string>AppIcon29x29</string>
                    <string>AppIcon40x40</string>
                    <string>AppIcon60x60</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
                <array>
                    <string>AppIcon29x29</string>
                    <string>AppIcon40x40</string>
                    <string>AppIcon60x60</string>
                    <string>AppIcon76x76</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The closest I've come is this:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(outputFolder + "\\Info.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> output = doc.Descendants("key").Where(n => (string)n.Value == "CFBundleIconFiles");
foreach (XElement a in output)
    MessageBox.Show((a.NextNode as XElement).Value);
```

This makes two alerts appear, the first says: "AppIcon29x29AppIcon40x40AppIcon60x60" for the first one and the second says "AppIcon29x29AppIcon40x40AppIcon60x60AppIcon76x76" which is annoying because I'm so close yet so far. I also feel like I'm doing this in an awful way that will make a few of you cringe.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I want the strings in the CFBundleIconFiles array.

Comment: What all info you want to extract?

Comment: Oops, completely forgot to mention that. I want the icon names under CFBundleIconFiles: AppIcon29x29 etc.

Comment: You are getting the expected output thn? Or you just want icon names from first node?

Comment: I'm getting an output of "AppIcon29x29AppIcon40x40AppIcon60x60" but I can't split it reliably as the filenames vary so much. I was hoping to read the filenames into an array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> output = doc.Descendants("key")
  .Where(n => n.Value == "CFBundleIconFiles");

IEnumerable<string> result = 
  output.SelectMany(a => 
    (a.NextNode as XElement).Descendants().Select(n => n.Value));

MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```